# how to ignore parent_id in duplicate quotes in mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have mysql database table structure like below:

```
quote_id     parent_id
-----------------------
1              NULL
2              NULL
3              2
4              3
5              4
6              NULL
```

I want to display the details in results like below.

```
quote_id     parent_id
-----------------------
1              NULL
3              2 
5              4 
6              NULL
```

How can I construct my sql query for this result? 
(simply i want to ignore duplicate parent id's except NULL values)

this is a quotation table and once a quotation has been edited, the edited quote will update the quotations table as a child quote of the original quote.

here i want avoid previous(edited) quotes and only show the latest  in the result.

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: "i want to ignore duplicate parent id's" - But the expected output shows `null` twice? In fact, it doesn't even match up with the original table contents.

Comment: @Jack yes you are correct, my bad. i wanted to ignore duplicate parent id's except NULL values. i corrected it.

Comment: Okay, but why does `4 => 3` become `5 => 4`?

Comment: once a quote is updated [edited] quote will insert as a new quote and the original quote will be the parent (parent_id) of that quote. hope you got what i mean. :)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't (get what you mean). So you're not talking about a SELECT query?

Comment: Its a mysql database table and trying to query the expected result as i've explain above. :)

Answer (score 2):

How about constructing a statement using `UNION`? The upper query gets the list of `quote_id` without `parent_id` while the lower query gets the list of lowest `quote_id` for every `parent_id`.

```
SELECT quote_id, parent_id
FROM TableName
WHERE parent_id IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT MIN(quote_id) AS quote_id, parent_id
FROM TableName
WHERE parent_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY parent_id
ORDER BY quote_id
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/259fa/1)

Without using `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT MIN(quote_id) AS quote_id, parent_id
FROM TableName
GROUP BY IFNULL(parent_id, RAND())
ORDER BY quote_id
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/259fa/2)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, and your answer was correct for the question, 

since i had a mistake with result view and now changed the result view. Could you please recheck it? I'm sorry for amendments. Thanks